# Python 2.7: Searching for specific text in Korean

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'd like to parse URLs where HTML looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row">채용부문</th>
    <td>서비스 개발</td>
</tr>
```

*(It's just an example, there is much more Korean mixed with English and HTML tags etc.)*

And upon finding 채용부문 (same word within `<th>` tags for all URLs), I want to extract 서비스 개발 (this word is different everywhere) and, say, store it in DB.

What is the best way to do this?

I didn't have any luck using codes from [Code Table Korean Hangul](http://memory.loc.gov/diglib/codetables/9.3.html), but I guess I was just doing something wrong. For example: using string `'\uC9C0'` (code for 지) as a keyword didn't help me to find word 지역.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you encounter character coding problem. I do not know korean language.
but I can give you an example for Chinese, maybe you can learn from it.

1.txt:

```
<tr>
   <th scope="row">我们</th>
   <td>我们是冠军</td>
</tr>
```

a.py:

```
# coding=utf-8
with open("1.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        can_line = line.decode('gbk') # line 1
        pos = can_line.find(u'冠军') # line 2
        if pos >= 0:
            print line
```

The above code will output:

```
<td>我们是冠军</td>
```

But if we do not have line1, and do not add 'u' before the keyword you want to find in line 2, you will get nothing.

Here you must know python internal will use unicode to store things, line1 will change line(with gbk coding) to unicode, while line2 also change '冠军'(with utf-8 coding) to unicode too, so two unicode can be compared, then find works.

I am not sure how it work in korea language, but I think for east asia language, it maybe similar, just FYI.

Comment: Hey, Atline! It works perfect with Korean except when I'm trying to `urllib.urlopen` instead of opening a .txt file I get `UnicodeDecodeError` all the time. Do you know, by any chance, how to fix this?

Comment: Yeah, in line 1, we use gbk, because the file is gbk encoding. If from web, you had to know the coding of the webpage. If you use decode('gbk'), but the html is not 'gbk' coding, it will report something like UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode bytes in position 15-16: illegal multibyte sequence. That means the web page is not such coding, you had to find the coding, use firefox, right click, see the page information, you may find the encoding of the web.